# Transform instance method to abstract method when overriding

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, abstract, overriding

**I've read in the Java SE Specification the following and did not fully understand it:** [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1)

> If, for example, a class declares two public methods with the same name , and a subclass overrides one of them, the subclass still inherits the other method.

**And**

> If the method not inherited is declared in a class, or the method not inherited is declared in an interface and the new declaration is abstract, then the new declaration is said to override it.

Doesn't it **match** this situation ?

```
public class Parent{

    public void method(){
        System.out.println("Call inside parent class");
    }
}
```

and

```
public abstract class Child extends Parent{

    public abstract void method();
}
```

*Can you please clarify ? Is this an overriding ?*

Comment: Why ddin't you use `@Override` and let the compiler answer?

Answer (score 0):

The two sentences aren't particularly related: the first is just giving an example for previous sentence.

This situation matches the second sentences, but not the first, so this would be an example of overriding as opposed to implementing or hiding.

An example for the first sentences would be

```
public class Parent {
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Call inside parent class");
    }

    public void method(int i) {
        System.out.println("Call method(int) inside parent class");
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{
    public void method() {
    }
}
```

Here, `Child` overrides `method()` and inherits `method(int i)`, so if you call `new Child().method(0)`, the string will get printed.

Comment: Yeah, I just posted the first sentence so that you could tell what the "method not inherited" statement from the second sentence refers to